# How to parent two objects in python

Tags: python, scripting

How to parent two object without selecting them manually in blender python scripting console? I want parent object which stored in variable like

Add a cube at the origin:

```
a=bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
```

Create an empty object:

```
b=bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type="SPHERE")
```

How to parent a to b?

Answer (score 4):

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
a = bpy.context.object
bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type="SPHERE")
b = bpy.context.object
const = b.constraints.new(type='CHILD_OF')
const.target = a
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to set a parent for an object is by accessing its `parent` property:

```
import bpy

# Create cube and reference the cube object
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
cube = bpy.context.object

# Create sphere empty and reference the empty object
bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type="SPHERE")
empty = bpy.context.object

# Set the sphere empty as the parent of the cube object
cube.parent = empty
```

Comment: The drawback there is that the child will snap to the parents location, if they had been positioned first. You can select both, make the parent active and use `bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='OBJECT')` to fill in the matrix to keep the child offset.